# Issues wiring up a new Angular controller module

Tags: angularjs

I wonder if someone could assist me in figuring out how to wire up my new angular service module.

I keep getting the same Javascript error :

```
Error: [$injector] Unknown provider: gridHierarchyServiceProvider" <-- gridHierarchyService
```

My new services/gridHierarchyService.js file :

```
(function () {
 'use strict';
 var controllerId = 'gridHierarchyService';
 angular.module('app').controller(controllerId, ['common', gridHierarchyService]);

 function gridHierarchyService(common) {
    var service = {
        getDataSourceSchema: getDataSourceSchema
    };
    return service;

    function getDataSourceSchema() {
        var i = 1;
        // TESTING...
    }
  }
 });
```

and in my dashboard.js file, I attempt to inject this new service module:

```
(function () {
'use strict';
var controllerId = 'dashboard';
angular.module('app').controller(controllerId, ['common', 'datacontext', 'gridHierarchyService', dashboard]);

function dashboard(common, datacontext, gridHierarchyService) {
            ...
}
```

and of course I'm loading it up in my index.html:

```
 <!-- app Services -->
<script src="app/services/datacontext.js"></script>
<script src="app/services/gridHierarchyService.js"></script>
<script src="app/services/directives.js"></script>
```

However, I'm clearing missing something here.

I also tried mimicking my datacontext.js service, using the .factory() call:

```
 angular.module('app').factory(serviceI,d [...]);
```

but it doesn't work.

```
        ========== UPDATE !!! ============
```

I'm happy to say it was a very easy fix, and thanks to the community here !

WORKING SERVICE :

```
 (function () {
'use strict';
var serviceId = 'gridHierarchyService';
angular.module('app').factory(serviceId, ['common', gridHierarchyService]);

function gridHierarchyService(common) {
    var service = {
        getDataSourceSchema: getDataSourceSchema
    };
    return service;

    function getDataSourceSchema() {
        var i = 1;
        i = 2;
    }
}
})();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that you are defining your controllers inside anonymous functions but that you never execute those anonymous functions.

Your code:

```
(function(){
   //declarations
   alert('You will never see me because I do not execute');
});
```

Fixed code (notice the parens at the end):

```
(function(){
   //declarations
   alert('You can see me!');
})();
```

See the above code run here: http://jsfiddle.net/wilsonjonash/cDBc7/

See more about the module pattern here:
 http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html

Also, you were right to try `factory` for a service.  To make your gridHierarchyService into a service (rather than a controller), just change `controller` to `factory` or `service` in

```
 var controllerId = 'gridHierarchyService';
 angular.module('app').controller(controllerId, ['common', gridHierarchyService]);
```

Hope that does the trick for you.

Comment: Good catch! I've done this once or twice myself ;) Going to delete my answer, since it was not correct.

Comment: BINGO ! Thanks for your time Jonathan Wilson - much appreciated. And thanks also for your prior input, Sunil D.